# Maximum flux in transformers

Tags: homework

What is meant by maximum flux here? How can I calculate it? I could calculate the rest of the question comfortably.

[image]

Comment: The magnetic flux is usually given in Volt-seconds (also known as Weber). Maybe that helps a bit.

Comment: `I could calculate [primary and secondary currents and secondary voltage] comfortably.` There is already a bit of guesswork involved in getting the currents: For flux, assume voltages sinusoidal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't know the area of the core. However, you're not being asked for the flux density, Teslas. You are being asked for the flux, Webers.

You have been given the volts per turn, and the frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Use the general transformer equation or EMF equation of the transformer.

$$E_1 = 4.44 f \phi_{Max} N_1$$
$$E_2 = 4.44 f \phi_{Max} N_2$$

[EMF Equation of Transformer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/emf-equation-of-transformer-turns-and-transformation-ratio-of-transformer)